# Removing camera distortion Rust computer vision

Tags: rust, computer-vision

I'm trying to remove distortion from a camera. In `python` you'd use openCV `calibrateCamera` like [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html) which would generate a camera matrix and distortion coefficients which look something like this:

```
    {
        "K": [
            [
                709.1235670254288,
                0.0,
                503.3777803177343
            ],
            [
                0.0,
                762.6123316058502,
                325.17231267609463
            ],
            [
                0.0,
                0.0,
                1.0
            ]
        ],
        "d": [
            -0.3387691660064381,
            0.038463156829204495,
            -0.006743169019715634,
            -0.005326145779068505,
            0.14363490033086238
        ],
        "width": "800",
        "height": "600",
        "camera": "0"
    },
```

I want to replicate this in Rust. Alternatively, without using the chess board approach you can manually input at least 6 corresponding points in order to calculate the matrix. In Rust there's `dlt` crate ([link](https://github.com/strawlab/dlt)) which can generate (if i understand correctly) this matrix. However it's a different format and i'm unable to figure out how to use it further. TO be honest i've considered it might work with [this](https://docs.rs/imageproc/latest/imageproc/geometric_transformations/struct.Projection.html#method.from_matrix) `imageproc::geometric_transformations::Projection:from_matrix` but it requires a 9-element array.

Any help would be appreciated. Using the openCV rust bindings are not helpful, they're fairly unstable at this point.

DLT crate matrix output:

```
[
    [0.927944628653911, -0.00396867519830716, -2.9083465040716445e-5], 
    [0.008799148019952768, 0.9597282376057464, 1.6532613813528404e-5], 
    [-1.304535025948496e-10, -1.61673678083447e-14, 0.0], 
    [18.28896299924497, 22.63046353374526, 1.0]
]
```

*edit: transposing that and making near-zero easy to spot:*

```
[[ 0.92794,  0.0088 , -0.     , 18.28896],
 [-0.00397,  0.95973, -0.     , 22.63046],
 [-0.00003,  0.00002,  0.     ,  1.     ]]
```

Comment: that "DLC crate" (you mean DLT, right?) matrix is seriously messed up. I can't figure out what it's supposed to do. it's 4x3, which is insane. it looks transposed, which is even more insane. it looks like _some_ identity, then a complete zero row/column, then some translation part, is this garbage?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz DLT, edited, thanks. I don't know, that's what it outputs and i've tested it by manually picking real points on the image (where they are now x,y, and z=0) and using a drawn grid to establish where they should actually be and the above 4x3 matrix was the output.

Comment: The matrix returned by `dlt` is [3x4](https://docs.rs/dlt/latest/dlt/fn.dlt.html). It seems that you are printing it transposed. This 3x4 matrix is a standard form in much computer vision. 2 seconds of searching gives me [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_matrix) and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38009/3x4-camera-matrix-from-blender-camera).

Comment: The `dlt` is the "direct **linear** transform" and therefore specifically will not find the non-linear distortion coefficients (`d`) you have listed.

Comment: are you saying the third (of four) columns being practically all-zero is a sensible result, @AndrewStraw? -- I'm sure nobody expects distortion coefficients in a camera matrix. those values are absurd no matter what.

Comment: @AndrewStraw i'm simply printing the output `    let pmat = dlt_corresponding(&[top, bot, left, right, center, another_point], 1e-10).unwrap(); println!("{:?}", pmat);`. Is the transposed output the `K` returned by the opencv version?

Comment: @Mike the in-memory representation of nalgebra is column major (probably to be compatible with OpenGL and other computer graphics libraries). I think you are printing the memory representation not the rows and columns you think you are.

Comment: See https://github.com/strawlab/dlt/tree/main/dlt-examples for an example of how to use the `dlt` crate (and verification that it does not give garbage, messed up, transposed results). Again, though, it won't return radial (or other non-linear) distortion values.

Comment: why is the third column all close to zero?